# Get attributes of children in a recursive tree structure unless it's a leaf node

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tree, overriding, getter, recursive-datastructures

I have a recursive tree structure for handling my categories. Each leaf category can have zero or more deals. The categories is defined by

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_category_id"
  belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: "Category"

  has_many :deal_categories
  has_many :deals, through: :deal_categories

  def leaf?
    !has_sub_categories?
  end

  def has_sub_categories?
    !sub_categories.empty?
  end
end
```

`Deals` and `DealCategories` looks like follows:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :deal_categories
end

class DealCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deal
  belongs_to :category
end
```

There are also some validations making sure that `Deals` only **can exist as leaf categories**. Thus, if I call `category.deals` on a leaf node I get some deals, and if I call it on a root node I get an empty result. All good.

But now I want `category.deals` to return the deals of it's children if it's not a root node. My approach has been to override the following method in my `Category` class as follows:

```
  alias_method :original_deals, :deals
  def deals
    if leaf?
      self.original_deals
    else
      self.sub_categories.deals
    end
  end
```

This however does not work as I can't call `deals` directly on `sub_categories`, the error being

```
undefined method `deals' for #<Category::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000009243d40>
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call deals on sub_categories because it is not a category...it is a collection of categories.  Instead you could do something like

```
sub_categories.reduce([]) { |union, sub_category| union + sub_category.deals }
```

Using reduce creates a memo object (represented by the union variable) and the evaluation of the block becomes the new memo object.  I am starting with an empty array and add in the result of calling deals on each sub_category in your sub_categories collection.